# Could electricity propel Curiosity on Venus?

Tags: rovers, venus, power, rtg, movement

To-date the humans have dispatched surface missions to

- [Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars)
- [Luna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)
- [Venus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus)

Mars has a thin atmosphere. Luna lacks one. Venus has a soup-thick atmosphere.
Landing a static craft on Venus is one thing. Exploration, rather **mobile** exploration would be a different cup of tea altogether given the alien (pardon the pun!) atmosphere - high pressure, high wind force.

On Mars, and Luna electricity serves as the motive power - generated either by an [RTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator), or by [PV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photovoltaic_module) arrays, or some form of batteries.

Assuming the [Curiosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_rover) rover is capable of surviving the Venerean atmosphere, could electricity serve as it's motive power at 93 bar? [ (+: Or a rover equaling Curiosity in terms of mass, and payload. ]

Comment: We've also done a soft landing on the asteroid Eros: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEAR_Shoemaker#Orbits_and_landing

Comment: There was also a succesful landing on the Saturn moon Titan - done by the Huygens lander. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens_(spacecraft)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a good assumption.  Curiosity would die a *very* quick thermal death on the surface of Venus.

But to answer your question, Curiosity's MMRTG would work on Venus and provide power.  The smaller temperature delta reduces the efficiency of conversion, but its not too bad.  See [this paper](http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?act=Attach&type=post&id=23200).

The atmospheric density and wind are not a factor at all for rover speeds and Venus wind speeds.  The wind at the surface is $0.1$ to $1\,\mathrm{m\over s}$.  The density is $67\,\mathrm{kg\over m^3}$.  So maybe $100\,\mathrm{N}$ over $3\,\mathrm{m}^2$ in a $1\,\mathrm{m\over s}$ wind.  The torque of the wheels is enormous, and wouldn't even notice that.  *Each* of the six wheels of Curiosity generates almost $3000\,\mathrm{N}$ of force when fully engaged.  $100\,\mathrm{N}$ at $0.05\,\mathrm{m\over s}$ is just $5\,\mathrm{W}$ of motive power.

You'd need to be careful to protect your soil samples so they don't blow away on the way from the ground to the instrument.  I'd worry more about the viscous drag when your wheels melt ...

Comment: I'm sorry the question wasn't clear. More than the temperature I'm concerned about the _effort_ involved in motion under 93 Bar. Would 300W be adequate?

Comment: The start of this answer should be modified to match the edited question.

Answer (score 6):

The equation for [aerodynamic drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29) is: 
$$
        P_d = \mathbf{F}_d \cdot \mathbf{v} = \tfrac12 \rho v^3 A C_d
$$
[Curiosity](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/education/marsrover.cfm) has a max. speed of 5 cm/s (0.18 km/h). Air density $\rho$ of Venus is 67 $kg/m^3$, where on Earth it's 1.2 $kg/m^3$.
I'll guesstimate frontal area A = 4 $m^2$ and $C_d$ = 1, then at 5 cm/s the drag force due to the rover's own speed is 0.016 N. The drag from wind speed (as @Mark calculated) is much higher, but still nothing to worry about.
Curiosity has up to [4000 Nm](http://jalopnik.com/5930877/the-ford-raptor-goes-head-to-head-against-mars-rover) of torque available, or 16 kN of force. That's with 110 W per wheel.